# Calculus III: Find the values of x and the sum for which the series converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given:

∑
    
      n
      =
      0
    
    ∞
  
  (
  
    e
    x
  
  
    )
    n
  
  =
  
    1
    
      1
      −
      
        e
        x

I need to find the domain but im stuck because: -1 <= x <= 1. In this case x is e^x. How do I find the domain for which x converges?

This is out of section 11.2 of the James Stewart Calculus book.

Comment: I am tempted to answer the domain with all real numbers.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(e^x)^n=\frac1{1-e^x}$$

if $|e^x|<1,-1<e^x<1\iff-\infty<x<0$

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply.

Comment: Good job of decrypting.