# Series uniform/converges at some $x$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not sure how to do the following problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

For which values of $x$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-nx}$ converge?

I also learned about uniform convergence recently, so is there a way to see on what intervals the above series is uniformly convergent?

Comment: This is just  differentiattion of  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008538/calculus-iii-find-the-values-of-x-and-the-sum-for-which-the-series-converges

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Wouldn't the derivative of the one you linked be $e^{xn}\cdot \frac{d}{dx} (xn)=e^{xn}\cdot n=ne^{xn}?$

Comment: A little adjustment required : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(e^{-x})^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referenced above, the series converges for $x > 0$.

**Uniform Convergence**

For uniform convergence on an interval $I$ we must have

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sup_{x \in I}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}ke^{-kx} = 0.$$

Note that for $I = [\delta,\infty)$ with  $\delta > 0$, we have  $|ne^{-nx}| \leq ne^{-n\delta}$ and the Weierstrass M-Test shows the series converges uniformly on $[\delta,\infty)$.

However, for $I = (0,\infty)$ we have

$$\sup_{x \in I}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}ke^{-kx} \geq\sup_{x \in I}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}ke^{-kx} \geq \sup_{x \in I} n^2 e^{-2nx} = n^2\rightarrow \infty$$

and the series does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I think the series is not uniformly convergent for $[0,\infty)$, but I think it is uniformly convergent on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Mariattta:  The series diverges for $x=0$ so we don't even consider uniform convergence on the closed interval $[0,\infty)$. It is not uniformly convergent on $(0,\infty)$ because we can find a sequence  of x values approaching 0 that makes partial sums deviate from sum by more than a fixed value for every n

Comment: Uniform convergence on $(0,\infty)$ is not the same as uniform convergence on $[\delta,\infty)$ for every $\delta >0$.